# How to make fixed page template?

Tags: html, css

i want do fixed page height without scrolling, header fixed on top,  and fill center to the remainder of the page. Center area will be have own scrolling bar when content overflow.

I set height 100% for central div, but this height ≠ height free space between top and bottom blocks.

What can i do? Many thanks!

[`Look code on jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/9xrz9mbf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a js fiddle which i have created with the points that i have understood from your problem.
I am using jquery `$( window ).height()` for getting browser viewport height.
By subtracting the height of header and footer  (50px + 50px =100px) from browser viewport height i will get the height of extra space.
This height will be equal to the content height.

check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bnx4uuse/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div around your center div.
Set it to full screen and pad:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 150px; /* size of your header */
padding-bottom: 100px; /* size of your footer */
```

On your center div you set overflow:

```
overflow: auto
```

The `overflow` property hides the extra content and adds a scrollbar to your div.

You header will have:

```
height: 150px; /* your desired size */
position: fixed; /* or absolute */
top: 0px;
```

Your footer will have:

```
height: 100px; /* your desired size */
position: fixed; /* or absolute */
bottom: 0px;
```

Then you have a "full-screen" app (full-window in that case)

Comment: Thanks, but i can use fixed sizes - page must be full size of screen

Comment: hmm... then I suggest a wrapper around your center div at 100% width and height with paddings the size of your header and footer.
Header and footer with position absolute or fixed, top 0 and bottom 0 respectively. Your center div using overflow: auto. Then you have a fullscreen app.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body {height:100%; }
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body { border:1px solid blue;  }

#head {background-color:#FC6; height:50px;position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;}
#center {background-color:#3CC; height:100%;margin:49px 0px; }
#foot {background-color:#9C0; height:50px;position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xrz9mbf/4/